# Data anonymization in R

Tags: r

I was trying to run the below code to mask the data in 2 columns, but failing with below error:

```
setwd("/cloud/project/CX")

Credit_tbl <-read.csv(file = 'Sample_data.csv',sep = ",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

anonymize <- function(x, algo="crc32"){
  unq_hashes <- vapply(unique(x), function(object) digest(object, algo=algo), FUN.VALUE="", USE.NAMES=TRUE)
  unname(unq_hashes[x])
}

cols_to_mask <- c("Email","Phone")

Credit_tbl[,cols_to_mask := lapply(.SD, anonymize),.SDcols=cols_to_mask,with=FALSE]
```

Error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(Credit_tbl, , `:=`(cols_to_mask, lapply(.SD,
>   anonymize)),  :    unused arguments (.SDcols = cols_to_mask, with =
>   FALSE)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Credit_tbl <-structure(list(ID = c(10L, 20L), Email = c("test@gmail.com", 
                                                        "abc@gmail.com")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
                                                        ))
anonymize <- function(x, algo="crc32"){
  unq_hashes <- vapply(unique(x), function(object) digest(object, algo=algo), FUN.VALUE="", USE.NAMES=TRUE)
  unname(unq_hashes[x])
}

cols_to_mask <- c("Email")
Credit_tbl[,cols_to_mask := lapply(.SD, anonymize),.SDcols=cols_to_mask,with=FALSE]

expected results:

Email
913ad86c
921485db

Comment: But failing with below error
Error in `[.data.frame`(Credit_tbl, , `:=`(cols_to_mask, lapply(.SD, anonymize)),  : unused arguments (.SDcols = cols_to_mask, with = FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dataframe and you are using `data.table` syntax.

Convert dataframe to `data.table` and apply the function.

```
library(data.table)
library(digest)

cols_to_mask <- c("Email","Phone")

anonymize <- function(x, algo="crc32") {
    sapply(x, function(y) if(y == "" | is.na(y)) "" else digest(y, algo = algo))
}

setDT(Credit_tbl)
Credit_tbl[, (cols_to_mask) := lapply(.SD, anonymize), .SDcols = cols_to_mask]
```

Without changing to `data.table` you can apply the function using `lapply` :

```
Credit_tbl[cols_to_mask] <- lapply(Credit_tbl[cols_to_mask], anonymize)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak 
I've changed code to convert dataframe to data.table and now I'm getting expected result for email but for phone numbers, all the values were converted to 
<NA>, as below.

 ID  Name                            Email Phone   Survey
1: 10  Ravi e9678a9267018fb55f357b79b856d561  <NA> Survey 1
2: 20  John 559bfd75952e5c08a0b637bf59b1e0f1  <NA> Survey 2
3: 30 Smith 690ef5d2cb4095950c14a20c6e5fee03  <NA> Survey 3
4: 40 Kevin                             <NA>  <NA> Survey 3

do we need to use different algorithm for phone numbers instead of "crc32" ?

Comment: @NPK I think your `anonymize` is function is complex. Can you try the updated answer? "crc32" works with numbers as well.

Comment: Thank you Ronak
I did try with the updated code and it worked perfectly, but only one thing how do we change the code to apply the anonymize function where values are not Null. If Null leave as is. 
much appreciated your help

Comment: @NPK By Null do you mean `NA` ? If so, you can use `sapply(x, function(y) if(is.na(y)) NA else digest(x, algo = algo))` in the function.

Comment: By Null means empty value, i just want to leave as is there is no value. I've change the code as below and now getting same encrypted value for all the data 
And 'NA' valued applied only for email address only

anonymize <- function(x, algo="crc32"){
  sapply(x, function(y) if(is.na(y)) NA else digest(x, algo = algo))
}

Comment: @NPK Sorry it should be `y` in `digest` instead of `x`. If you have `NA` values do `sapply(x, function(y) if(is.na(y)) NA else digest(y, algo = algo))` or for empty values use `sapply(x, function(y) if(y == "") "" else digest(y, algo = algo))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211776/discussion-between-npk-and-ronak-shah).